# My pi approximation using the wallis' method doesn't work and I have no idea what's going on

Tags: python, math, pi, approximation

I'm working in Python 3.7 and part of my assignment is to define Wallis' approach to approximating pi. I'm a maths student, not cut out for doing computer science and could really use some help, this is worth 40% of my grade in total and I can't do any more without defining this properly. Here is the code I have currently written:

```
def pi_wallis(n):
        z=1
        for k in range(n):
                a=(2.0*k)//((2.0*k)-1.0)
                b=(2.0*k)//((2.0*k)+1.0)
                z*=(a*b)
        return z
```

No matter the input I enter, I always get -0.0, can anyone shed any light as to why? I first had z=0 and have tried changing to z=2, still get -0.0

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: @DeepSpace oh yeah you're right, however the approximation is to multiply each iteration, so how do i do this without getting zero, let z=1?

Comment: @DeepSpace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product seems to suggest multiplcation. I guess starting with `z = 1.0` would work.

Comment: @PeterWood I've just tried changing z to 1 and 2 and still -0.0 is the output

Answer (score 2):

You are using integer division (`//`), which means that it's enough for one fraction (for example, `2/3` in the first iteration) to make the entire sequence 0.

You should use floating point division (`/`). It will also be clearer if you start the sequence from 1 and finish in `n + 1` (since `range` is exclusive in the end).

```
def pi_wallis(n):
    z = 1
    for k in range(1, n + 1):
        a = (2.0*k) / ((2.0*k)-1.0)
        b = (2.0*k) / ((2.0*k)+1.0)
        z *= a*b
    return z
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried doing floating point earlier but kept getting -0.0 as well I don't really understand the difference too well, changing my range to (1,n+1) worked, i forgot to return 2*z as well because the series gives pi/2, legend.

Comment: On your earlier result: `(2.0*0.) / (0-1.0) -> (0.0) / (-1.0) -> -0.0` Zero can be signed.